# Как отладить программу на python?

Tags: python, visual-studio, ide

Перешел недавно на python, т.к. нужно рабоать с нейросетью. Перешел с языков со строгой типизацией (C++, C#), так вот там отлаживать программу просто: ты видишь где какие переменные у тебя в программе, сколько переменных принимает функция и какой тип возвращает. Самое главное, что среда разработки выдаст ошибку ПЕРЕД выполнением программы. На питоне же нужно сначала запустить программу и только тогда тебе покажет где ошибка: то там лишнюю переменную в функцию передал, то функция вернула не тот тип и т.п. Когда программа большая, отладка на питоне занимает больше времени чем написание кода. Как решить эту проблему? Или это участь языков-интерпретаторов с динамической типизацией?

Comment: Расставьте в своём коде [аннотации типов](https://habr.com/ru/company/lamoda/blog/432656/) и возьмите mypy и/или умную IDE, они вам проверят статическую типизацию перед выполнением программы. (Правда, частичную, потому что не во всех модулях эти самые аннотации типов вообще есть, так что придётся страдать всё равно)

Comment: Правильность выполнения команд (одной или нескольких) удобно проверять в командной строке интерпретатора Shell, непосредственно вводя их с клавиатуры.